# Install filezilla under linux mint

Tags: linux, ftp, file-transfer

I'm trying to upload some files on my website and I'm running Linux Mint latest version. So, they told me i need a ftp client to do this, and also read about an hour - "top ftp clients". For me filezilla is good, but i don't know how to run it on Linux.

Any sugestations ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Filezilla client should be readily available in Mint's package management system. You can double check its availability with by opening up a terminal window and running:

```
apt-cache show filezilla
```

This should show you information about the package. To install, run:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install filezilla -y
```

Once you've installed it, just type it into the command line to run it, or go through your graphical "start" menu and find it there. Here's a [visual guide](https://www.linuxhelp.com/how-to-install-filezilla-on-linuxmint-18-03) for further reference. For general Filezilla usage, which should have the same UI regardless of the OS, see [here](https://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Documentation).

You should be careful using the default **ftp** client since it offers no enccryption. Thus, passwords and other sensitive data you may transmit over FTP are easily sniffed. Thankfully, if you do want to go the command line route, you can use the `sftp` client which has the same command syntax as `ftp`.

Comment: I just did these commands and there is an error stating that the repository cant be reached.

Comment: E: Failed to fetch http://lug.mtu.edu/ubuntu/pool/universe/f/filezilla/filezilla-common_3.46.3-1build1_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 141.219.188.20 80]

Comment: This question was for Linux Mint so if you're using Ubuntu, I'm not sure what could be going wrong. Make sure you've got an up-to-date package list(run `apt update`). Also, you could compile Filezilla from source: https://filezilla-project.org/download.php?show_all=1

Answer (score 1):

Although you can install [Filezilla](https://filezilla-project.org/download.php?platform=linux) or [gFTP](https://www.gftp.org/), the best way to ftp into your website would just be to issue the built-in [ftp command](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-use-ftp-on-the-linux-shell/) on your Linux computer.

Your IP may be different, this is just an example:

```
ftp 127.0.0.1
```

You can then use the put or get commands in the FTP shell to send/receive files.